# How can i solve a undefined index problem while using $_POST on the error line?

Tags: php

im new to all of this programming stuff and PHP. So every time i try to run this code the web page says:

> Notice: Undefined index: tiempos in C:\wamp64\www\pruebaaaa\Act 1.php
> on line 14

I really don't know why. This is the code.Thanks in advance. (Sorry if my English is bad)

```
<!doctype HTML>
<HTML>
<head>
<title>Act 1</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
 <form name="form1" method="POST" action="Act 1.php">
 Digite los segundos : <input name="tiempos" type="text" id="tiempos"> <br>
 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Calcular">
 </form>
 <?php
 $segundos = $_POST['tiempos'];
 $horas = $segundos/3600;
 $minutos = $segundos/60;
 print 'Segundos : ' . $segundos;
 print '<br> Minutos : ' . intval($minutos);
 print '<br> Horas : ' . intval ($horas);
 ?>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to check if the form has been submitted or not e.g `<?php if (isset($_POST['tiempos'])) { // rest of the code }`. If the form has not yet been submitted you will get the warning message since you are trying to access an index in the post data which yet does not exist.

Comment: At the top of the page add this echo '<pre>'; var_export($_POST); exit;

Answer (score 0):

The code to handle submit is executing before it has been submitted.  The easiest way to stop that is to check if the POST is not null, like this

```php
<!doctype HTML>
<HTML>
<head>
<title>Act 1</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
 <form name="form1" method="POST" action="Act 1.php">
 Digite los segundos : <input name="tiempos" type="text" id="tiempos"> <br>
 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Calcular">
 </form>
 <?php
if (isset ($_POST['submit']))  //<--- Checks if button has been pressed
{
 $segundos = $_POST['tiempos'] ?? 0;  //<--- Gives you 0 if the value is null
 $horas = $segundos/3600;
 $minutos = $segundos/60;
 print 'Segundos : ' . $segundos;
 print '<br> Minutos : ' . intval($minutos);
 print '<br> Horas : ' . intval ($horas);
}
 ?>
</body>
</html>
```